# jpg looks different in firefox 6 and 7 on Windows 7

Tags: css, firefox, windows-7, jpeg

[This](http://www.dps.state.ok.us/ohp/tngrct/ohpweb/index.html) website renders a background jpg differently than it did in Firefox 5 and below on Windows 7.  I know that's a bit confusing so I'll outline it.

**It works:**

All versions of firefox, chrome, and IE on windows XP

All versions of chrome, IE, and firefox 5 and below on windows 7

Example:
[image]

**It doesn't work:**

Firefox 6 and above on Windows 7

Example:
[image]

The website is repeating the gradient jpg horizontally.  It then tries to make the background color the same color as the bottom of that gradient.

Thanks again SO.

Comment: I tried loading that page and it just times out. At a first glance it may be to do with embedded colour profiles, although I can't see the image to check if it has one embedded or not.

Comment: Yeah, no doubt that has to do with the fact you are in the UK sorry about that.  I'll look into embedded color profiles.

Comment: @ktothez: I agree with Geoff Adams, most likely issue is that the machine where you see this issue uses some broken color profile. Btw, you should prefer PNG over GIF, it offers better quality and smaller file sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my Windows 7 / FF6, the gradient looks pretty smooth:

[image]

so I think that what you're seeing is machine specific.

However, you might have better results by using a .GIF with a transparent bottom (to fade to background color) rather than a .JPG.  In general, you've got better control over the colors in a .GIF because it's not a lossy format if you have few enough colors.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess it is.  I wonder what's up with this box.